# How to implement Stripe Checkout system in Node.js and Express.js (test mode)

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, checkout

so i'm quite new to stripe and trying to build a stripe checkout sysem for an ecommerce website, i believe i have setup the the backend and client code correctly but whenver i go into checkout url the following error pops up

[image]

earlier it also gave an error of windo.popup

here is my server.js file

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
require('dotenv').config()
import express from "express";

const cors = require("cors");
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY);

const corsOptions = {
  origin: "https://localhost:5173"
};

const app = express();
app.use(cors(corsOption));

app.use(express.json());
const path = require("path");
// currently
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
  app.use(express.static("build"));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Welcome to eShop website.");
});

const array = [];
const calculateOrderAmount = (items) => {
  items.map((item) => {
    const { price, cartQuantity } = item;
    const cartItemAmount = price * cartQuantity;
    return array.push(cartItemAmount);
  });
  const totalAmount = array.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + b;
  }, 0);

  return totalAmount * 100;
};

app.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("Received request:", req.body);
  const { items, shipping, description } = req.body;

  // Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: calculateOrderAmount(items),
    currency: "usd",
    automatic_payment_methods: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    description,
    shipping: {
      address: {
        line1: shipping.line1,
        line2: shipping.line2,
        city: shipping.city,
        country: shipping.country,
        postal_code: shipping.postal_code,
      },
      name: shipping.name,
      phone: shipping.phone,
    },
    // receipt_email: customerEmail
  });
  console.log("Sending response:", paymentIntent);
  res.send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
  });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5173;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Node server listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

here is my checkoutForm.jsx

```
import {
  PaymentElement,
  useElements,
  useStripe,
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./CheckoutForm.css";
import Card from "../card/Card";
import CheckoutSummary from "../checkoutSummary/CheckoutSummary";
import spinner from "../../assets/spinner.jpg";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectEmail, selectUserID } from "../../redux/slice/authSlice";
import {
  CLEAR_CART,
  selectCartItems,
  selectCartTotalAmount,
} from "../../redux/slice/CartSlice";
import { selectShippingAddress } from "../../redux/slice/CheckoutSlice";
import { Timestamp, addDoc, collection } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../../pages/firebase/config";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function CheckoutForm() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const userID = useSelector(selectUserID);
  const userEmail = useSelector(selectEmail);
  const cartItems = useSelector(selectCartItems);
  const cartTotalAmount = useSelector(selectCartTotalAmount);
  const shippingAddress = useSelector(selectShippingAddress);

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      if (!stripe) {
        return;
      }

      const clientSecret = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
        "payment_intent_client_secret"
      );

      if (!clientSecret) {
        return;
      }
    } catch (error) {}
  }, [stripe]);

  const saveOrder = () => {
    const today = new Date();
    const date = today.toDateString();
    const time = today.toLocaleTimeString();
    const orderConfig = {
      userID,
      userEmail,
      orderDate: date,
      orderTime: time,
      orderAmount: cartTotalAmount,
      orderStatus: "Order Placed...",
      cartItems,
      shippingAddress,
      createdAt: Timestamp.now().toDate(),
    };
    try {
      addDoc(collection(db, "orders"), orderConfig);
      dispatch(CLEAR_CART());
      toast.success("Order saved");
      navigate("/checkout-success");
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error(error.message);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setMessage(null);

    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      return;
    }

    setIsLoading(true);

    const confirmPayment = await stripe
      .confirmPayment({
        elements,
        confirmParams: {
          // Make sure to change this to your payment completion page
          return_url: "http://localhost:5173/checkout-success",
        },
        redirect: "if_required",
      })
      .then((result) => {
        // ok - paymentIntent // bad - error
        if (result.error) {
          toast.error(result.error.message);
          setMessage(result.error.message);
          return;
        }
        if (result.paymentIntent) {
          if (result.paymentIntent.status === "succeeded") {
            setIsLoading(false);
            toast.success("Payment successful");
            saveOrder();
          }
        }
      });

    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <div className={`container checkoutForm`}>
        <h2>Checkout</h2>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div>
            <Card cardClass="checkoutForm-card">
              <CheckoutSummary />
            </Card>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Card cardClass={`checkoutForm-card checkoutForm-pay`}>
              <h3>Stripe Checkout</h3>
              <PaymentElement id={styles["payment-element"]} />
              <button
                disabled={isLoading || !stripe || !elements}
                id="submit"
                className="checkoutForm-button"
              >
                <span id="button-text">
                  {isLoading ? (
                    <img
                      src={spinner}
                      alt="Loading..."
                      style={{ width: "20px" }}
                    />
                  ) : (
                    "Pay now"
                  )}
                </span>
              </button>
              {/* Show any error or success messages */}
              {message && <div id={styles["payment-message"]}>{message}</div>}
            </Card>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default CheckoutForm;
```

here is my Checkout.jsx where frontend i.e client side is setup

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  CALCULATE_SUBTOTAL,
  CALCULATE_TOTAL_QUANTITY,
  selectCartItems,
  selectCartTotalAmount
} from "../../redux/slice/CartSlice";
import { selectEmail } from "../../redux/slice/authSlice";
import {
  selectBillingAddress,
  selectShippingAddress
} from "../../redux/slice/CheckoutSlice";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import CheckoutForm from "../../components/checkoutForm/CheckoutForm";
import process from "process"



const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PK);

const Checkout = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("Initializing checkout...");
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState("");

  const cartItems = useSelector(selectCartItems);
  const totalAmount = useSelector(selectCartTotalAmount);
  const customerEmail = useSelector(selectEmail);

  const shippingAddress = useSelector(selectShippingAddress);
  const billingAddress = useSelector(selectBillingAddress);
console.log("checkout componenrt loaded")
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {

    dispatch(CALCULATE_SUBTOTAL());
    dispatch(CALCULATE_TOTAL_QUANTITY());
    
    }, [dispatch, cartItems]);

  const description = `eShop payment: email: ${customerEmail}, Amount: ${totalAmount}`;

  useEffect(() => {
    // http://localhost:4242/create-payment-intent
    // Create PaymentIntent as soon as the page loads
    fetch("http://localhost:5173/create-payment-intent", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        items: cartItems,
        userEmail: customerEmail,
        shipping: shippingAddress,
        billing: billingAddress,
        description,
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.ok) {
          return res.json();
        }
        return res.json().then((json) => Promise.reject(json));
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setClientSecret(data.clientSecret);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setMessage("Failed to initialize checkout");
        toast.error("Something went wrong!!!");
      });
  }, []);

  const appearance = {
    theme: "stripe",
  };
  const options = {
    clientSecret,
    appearance,
  };

  return (
    <>
      <section>
        <div className="container">{!clientSecret && <h3>{message}</h3>}</div>
      </section>
      {clientSecret && (
        <Elements options={options} stripe={stripePromise}>
          <CheckoutForm />
        </Elements>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Checkout;
```

i have setup the .env file correctly as

```
REACT_APP_STRIPE_PK="blah bla blah"
REACT_APP_STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY="private content"
PORT='5173'
NODE_ENV=test
```

the problem is that it is not been able to fetch the url in checkout it gives the toast error saying something went wrong

P.S: If you want more info just ask

Comment: Have you confirm REACT_APP_STRIPE_PK is the Publishable Key? The console error says it expects a String. Also second error is like your frontend can't find your backend endpoint to request.

Comment: @orakaro i believe that my REACT_APP_STRIPE_PK is correect, BTW my frontend is unable to find my backend as if the backend is not setup, so waht could be the cause for this error

Comment: @orakaro hey man can u help me in integrating/configuring backend, becuase it is the only reason why it is not wokring and as a result the frontend is unable to recognize the backend